# Evaluating Output Function in Mathematica when input does not specify variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am evaluating a partial derivative

```
    fx = D[m[x, y], x]
```

The output gives me an output in terms of x and y. I'm trying to evaluate the function using

```
    fx1 = fx/.{x-> 1.0, y-> 2.0}
```

but keeps giving me an answer like

```
    0.471328[1.0, 2.0]
```

But I only want the 0.471328

Comment: m is not defined correctly

Answer (score 0):

I can't even begin to guess what code you have written, and not shown, to get where you are, but

```
In[3]:= Head[0.471328[1.0, 2.0]]

Out[3]= 0.471328
```

will give you what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show one correct way to do this:

```
m[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + x y
fx[x_, y_] := D[m[x, y], x]
fx[x, y] /. {x -> 1.0, y -> 2.0}
(*
=> 4.
*)
```